# Aptana 3 and shell

Tags: shell, cakephp, aptana

How config Aptana Studio 3 for running CakePHP bake shell script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several times I came up to this thread while searching Stack Overflow and Google for an answer too. I noticed that Aptana 3 doesn't have a "Tools --> External Tools" item anymore, although Aptana 2 had this great feature by default.

I couldn't find any solutions, so I started to find out myself. For all people having the same problem, here's the solution:

The feature is there, but not available on default.

1. Open the "Web" perspective
2. Right click the "Web" perspective (right upper part of the screen)
3. Click "Customize..."
4. Go to the tab "Command Groups Availability"
5. Enable "External Tools" by checking its checkbox
6. Go to the tab "Menu Visibility"
7. Expand "Run" and enable "External Tools" by checking its checkbox
8. Press "OK" and you're ready to go.

To complete the whole case, here is the configuration I use for the CakePHP Bake External Tools. It's a little bit different than suggestions elsewehere, but it makes it independent for each project.

**CakePHP 1.x**

1. Open Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations
2. Create a program
3. Name: CakePHP Bake
4. Location:

   - Mac OSX: ${project_loc}/cake/console/cake
   - Windows: ${project_loc}/cake/console/cake.bat
5. Working Directory: ${project_loc}/app
6. Arguments: bake

Using ${project_loc} in the location (step 4) will locate the Cake console of your current project. While most projects in my case uses the latest version (currently 1.3 branche), older projects may still use the 1.2 or even the 1.1 branche. The bake console may differ from branche to branche.

**UPDATE Aug 22nd 2014**

As I've posted this solution in 2011 and people are still using this topic, here's how it works for the new CakePHP 2.x range.

1. Open Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations
2. Create a program
3. Name: CakePHP 2.x Bake
4. Location:

   - Mac OSX: ${project_loc}/lib/Cake/Console/cake
   - Windows: ${project_loc}/lib/Cake/Console/cake.bat
5. Working Directory: ${project_loc}/app
6. Arguments: bake

Comment: Hi, I upgrade my Aptana, and I use steps above, but I can't create New Program (my button is disable), maybe You know why?

Comment: @kicaj Although your post is from 2012, are you still having difficulties? If so, it might help to change your perspective (and making sure you're in a Web perspective) of Eclipse/Aptana

Furthermore I've just added some information regarding CakePHP 2.x branche.

Comment: @FlipperK I am using CakePHP 3.x and there is no app folder. I am using Aptana studio 3, build 3.6.1.2014. First of all there is no app folder any more. And there are lot of syntax errors at the starting of an array. It's just a hello world program created by composer and imported in aptana. I am a newbie and figuring out how to work with cake php and aptana. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

[LINK](http://webmanufactory.blogspot.com/2011/02/cakephp-cake-bake-is-awesome.html)
Aptana is built on eclipse. Search for eclipse solution.